# How to download GAE logs using maven plugin?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, logging, maven-gae-plugin

I am using the maven gae plugin for my build and deploy of google appengine app (under windows). All works as expected.

However - I notice its also possible to download the GAE with the same pluggin. It looks to me like something like:

```
mvn -DoutputFile=./test.log gae:logs
```

should work - however it just gets stuck at:

```
0% Beginning to retrieve log records...
```

and goes no further - what am I doing wrong?

Using

```
mvn -e
```

or

```
mvn -X
```

don't seem to provide any helpful output

Comment: I can add this to the official plugin, if you'd like. Just create a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an absolute path as well on OSX and it refuses to honor the `-DoutputFile` argument and puts the logs in `target/gae.log` no matter where I try and tell it to put it or name it instead.

So go look in your `project_dir/target/gae.log` file